#  Can't reach Storyboard object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, storyboard

So I have this XAML:

```
<ListBox Height="626" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="ItemList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Grid Height="50">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="ItemCountBGImageShow">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ItemCountBGImage"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="31" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Opacity="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Name="ItemCountBGImage" Width="31" Height="31" Source="/CafeKonto.wp7;component/Images/table_quantity.png" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  FontSize="25" Name="ItemName" Foreground="White" Tap="ItemName_Tap" Text="{Binding ItemName}" Margin="35,0,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="3" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="25" Name="ItemPrice" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding ItemPriceFormated}" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My problem is, I cannot start the animation from C#. ItemCountBGImageShow is not visible in the code behind. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access an item in an element's resource dictionary like that.

Give grid a name and then access it using it's Resources property.

Example:

XAML:

```
<Grid Name="Grid1" Height="50">
```

Code:

```
Storyboard ItemCountBGImageShow = (Storyboard)Grid1.Resources["ItemCountBGImageShow"];
```

Comment: That does not work either. I think it's because the Storyboard is within a Listbox. Somehow I need to fetch the right storyboard instance and start it.